# i have birthdate in the table , i need to find age between 30 to 70 how can I write sql query for that?

Tags: mysql, sql

begin age and end age find where age is between 30 to 70
i just have birth date in table

```
Birthday
01/22/1960 12:00:00 AM
10/14/1930 12:00:00 AM
11/15/1955 12:00:00 AM
05/20/1991 12:00:00 AM
06/10/2005 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use date comparisons.  Something like the following, depending on whether or not you want to include the end years:

```
where birthday <= curdate() - interval 30 year and
      birthday > curdate() - interval 71 year
```

Comment: we can use `-` to subtract dates from mysql?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia . . . As in this example?  Yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Birthday
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), birthday ) >= 30
AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), birthday ) <= 70
```